# load image from API in collection view (array of image url)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image, api

```
import UIKit

struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let images: [Location]
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    let imageloc: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imageloc = [Welcome]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageloc.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let url = URL(string: "http://swaminarayanwales.org.uk/DailyDarshan/ExportJsonV2.php?sMandir=Nairobi-Temple&Target=real&sm=sm)")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
                do{
                    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)
                    if let imgUrl = URL(string: jsonData.images[indexPath.row].imageloc){
                        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imgUrl){
                            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error occured")
                }
        }.resume()
        return cell
    }
}
```

i don't have xib i just have custom class of collectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

this is my whole code for getting image from API

Api has an array of image Urls

t think my code has a problem in function named cellForRowAt there i am unable to use array

how can i use array in it

As far as i know i should also pass array in second function nut when i use it in decoder it shows that it should be decoder type how can i access member imageLoc of Location struct for loading image

this is my API = http://swaminarayanwales.org.uk/DailyDarshan/ExportJsonV2.php?sMandir=Nairobi-Temple&Target=real&sm=sm)

Comment: Probably better doing some simple tutorials about UICollectionView. Your approach won´t work at all.

Comment: which approach should i use

Comment: but i want to do these now i already did simple tuts

Answer (score 0):

You can try SDWebImage.

Please check : https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

Method 1 :

`imgView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))`

Method 2 :

`if let imgUrl = URL(string: url) { cell.imgMain.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: strUrl)) { (img, erroe, cache, url) in if let er = error { print(er.localizedDescription) }else { print("success") } } }`

Comment: should i add these library ???

Comment: Yes, You have to add above library as per link mentioned.

Comment: Installation Guide : https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/Installation-Guide @helibhadeshiya

Comment: i am not able to understand these 2 methods can you explain + i am using swift 4.2 and excode 10.1

Comment: Did you added above library?

Comment: yes i added at first it was not shaing that error but after while it shows that error

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage

1. Install pod for SDWebImage  : `pod 'SDWebImage'`
2. Use some line of code to fetch your image

`import SDWebImage`

for indicator on your image

`your_image_name.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray`

fetch and show your server image on your image view

```
your_image_name.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: 'your_get_server_image'), placeholderImage:
UIImage(named: "your_place_holder_image_name"))
```

Comment: do i need to use urlSession  and jsonDecoder ?

Comment: what is your_get_server_image and your_place_holder_image_name ??

Comment: 'your_place_holder_image_name' you can set your placeholder image. Place holder image means if your image is empty or nil in server then your placeholder image will call

FULL CODE IS :

-> in CellForItem
cell. imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (dict['image_param_name'] as! String)), placeholderImage:
UIImage(named: "logo.png"))